# User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

When I use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method, it returns null. I am trying to make a method (based on `AccountController` of MVC) to change user's password. The problem is with `User.Identity.GetUserId()` returning null.

Look my controller and help if you can.

## Begin and constructor

```
protected ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; }
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

    public ClienteController()
    {
        this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
        //this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    }
```

## Login method

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(ClienteViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        Cliente cliente = ChecarAcesso(model);

        if (cliente != null)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, cliente.nomeCompletoCliente));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, cliente.emailCliente));

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();

            var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authenticationManager.SignOut();
            authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
            Session.Add("cliente", cliente);

            if (returnUrl != null)
            {
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AcessoNegado");
        }
    }
```

## The manage method that is not working

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Gerenciar(GerenciarClienteViewModel model)
    {
        //bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
        //ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Gerenciar");
        //if (hasPassword)
        //{
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.senhaAntiga, model.novaSenha);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Gerenciar", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
        //}

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null when the user is not login

Comment: Yes, but I am logged on web application :/. I already tested create a new user and log in with it. But, when I try to change password, that method says that UserID is null.

Comment: why do you have "  authenticationManager.SignOut();"? what happens if you remove it?

Comment: @ZoranP.: Sincerely, I don't know why I have "authenticationManager.SignOut();". I assusme that I used a example. So, I commented that line and still with the same problem.

Comment: can you show us your Startup.Auth.cs file? The only thing I can think of is that something is wrong with your Owin context...

Comment: although to be honest, I am not sure that GetUserId works with Claims... every time I used it I used  SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and when using Claims I was fetching properties differently.

Comment: This is my first time working with MVC, GetUserId and Claims :/. My Startup.Auth.cs:

    public partial class Startup
    {
       public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Cliente/Login")
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works for me. I get the ID of user using session, but I discovered that method `ChangePasswordAsync()` tries to create a new table on database. In my case, I already have a database. So I just create a method that receives session with user ID and change old password by the new password. Much more simple and it works.

Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 0):

I know you accepted an answer already, but I had this problem a few months back, and it turned out I needed to do it a little differently with this last version of MVC.

```
var id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: Why do we have to include WebMatrix.WebData into ASP.NET MVC application for it?